# Expand a specific GroupView programmatically

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expand

I have an `ExpandableListView` and everything is working fine. Now I want to be able to expand a specific `GroupView`.

The idea:
After a search query I got a result as a `String`. That `String` is then used to locate the `GroupView`, more accurate a `String` value in that `GroupView`. When the strings match I want to expand that `GroupView` and scroll to that position of the screen.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!yourExpandableListView.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
yourExpandableListView.expandGroup(groupPosition);
}
```

The above code used to expand the particular groupview programmatically.For that you have to get groupPosition. Upto my knowledge you cant able to match the group item string value, instead you can query and get string with id(groupPosition) using that groupPostion you can expand the particular GroupView.

Comment: I managed to make it work. It is kinda messy but it works :)
I'll accept your answer, because you took your time to help me. Cheers!